# running unittests \ integration tests in python

Tags: python, django, integration-testing, pytest

I have a Django project with multiple apps. Each app has a set of unittests. I'm using pytest as my test runner. We have gotten to a point that we want to start writing integration tests. I was wondering if there is any way to keep the naming convention and thus the auto discovery of pytest but still be able (via flag maybe?) to run the different test types. The most intuitive solution that comes to mind is some sort of decorator on test methods or even `TestCase` classes (something like Category in JUnit). 
something like:

```
@testtype('unittest')
def test_my_test(self):
    # do some testing

@testtype('integration')
def test_my_integration_test(self):
    # do some integration testing
```

and then i could run the test like:

```
py.test --type=integration
py.test --type=unittest
```

Is there such a thing? 
If not, the only other solution i can think about is to add a django command and "manually" build a testsuite and run it with pytest... I would prefer not to use this option. Is there any other solution that can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [mark test functions](https://pytest.org/latest/example/markers.html#marking-test-functions-and-selecting-them-for-a-run).

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.unittest
def test_my_test(self):
    # do some testing

@pytest.mark.integration
def test_my_integration_test(self):
    # do some integration testing
```

These custom markers must be [registered](http://pytest.org/latest/example/markers.html#registering-markers) in your pytest.ini file.

Then use the `-m` flag to run the marked tests

```
py.test -v -m unittest
```

Another option would be to split your tests into `unittest` and `integration` directories. Then you can run tests in a specific directory with:

```
py.test -v unittest
```

or

```
py.test -v integration
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this (without any config or code)

`pytest -o "python_functions=*_integration_test"`

You can also do this in module/class level, e.g.,

```
python_files = integration_test_*.py
python_classes = IntegrationTest
```

Ref:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions